# ElasticSearch Python highlights not being displayed in results

Tags: python, elasticsearch, highlight

I am trying to display highlights with my ElasticSearch results.

I don't get any syntax errors when I run this query, but I also don't see any highlights being displayed as expected. Can you suggest where I may be going wrong..

```
search_query = {
    'query': {
        'multi_match': {
            'query': query,
            'fields': ['title', 'text']
        }
    },
    'highlight': {
        'pre_tags': ['<b>', '<em>'],
        'post_tags': ['</b>', '</em>'],
        'fields': {
            'title': {}
        }
    }
}
```

My results show all the fields I expect to be return but not the `highlight` field.

I have tried several versions of similar syntax.

Edit: Adding a sample document.

```
doc = {
    title: 'The website title',
    image: 'https://thedomain.com/images/sample_image.jpg',
    text: 'blah blah blah .. etc.'
}
```

Sample search term: 'website'

I have added a mapping to the code that creates the index.

The mapping is:

```
request_body = {
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 1
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "index": 'true'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code to create the index is:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'scheme': 'http', 'port': 9200}])
es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=request_body)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample document and the search term?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have some kind of analyzer in the fields but running the example below in kibana devTools I got a positive result.

```
 response = get_client_es().indices.create(index="idx_test", body={
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}, ignore=400)

result = get_client_es().index(index="idx_test", body={
    "title": "The website title",
    "image": "https://thedomain.com/images/sample_image.jpg",
    "text": "blah blah blah .. etc."
}, refresh="wait_for")

print(result)

query = {
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "website",
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "text"
            ]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": [
            "<b>",
            "<em>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
            "</b>",
            "</em>"
        ],
        "fields": {
            "title": {}
        }
    }
}
result = get_client_es().search(index="idx_test", body=query)
print(result)
```

Results

```
{'acknowledged': True, 'shards_acknowledged': True, 'index': 'idx_test'}


{'_index': 'idx_test', '_id': 'ob5rEIUBSeG9S8LuvPKZ', '_version': 1, 'result': 'created', '_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 1, 'failed': 0}, '_seq_no': 0, '_primary_term': 1}


{'took': 2, 'timed_out': False, '_shards': {'total': 1, 'successful': 1, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0}, 'hits': {'total': {'value': 1, 'relation': 'eq'}, 'max_score': 0.2876821, 'hits': [{'_index': 'idx_test', '_id': 'ob5rEIUBSeG9S8LuvPKZ', '_score': 0.2876821, '_source': {'title': 'The website title', 'image': 'https://thedomain.com/images/sample_image.jpg', 'text': 'blah blah blah .. etc.'}, 'highlight': {'title': ['The <b>website</b> title']}}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, as far as I know I don't have any analyzers running, this is exactly the code we have. Is there anything else that might be wrong?

Comment: share your mapping maybe there is something different

Comment: I haven't provided a mapping as the search worked without it. I'll look into mappings and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Hi, I've added in the mapping which seems to work, the index is created and products added. However the highlighter still doesn't work.

Comment: I wrote code in python with your information. Its works. You can reproduce the code?